# QueryClass samples

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#

Anyone have sample code on the actual use of a QueryClass.  I can read the help and figure out how to make one but there is no code demonstrating the usage of a QueryClass.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with a QueryClass?  Assuming you're talking about SQL workspaces, once you have created your query class the most important thing you need to know is this: "From this point, the class can typically be consumed in the same way as an ITable or IFeatureClass reference from other data sources, keeping in mind that it is read-only."  Note that depending on whether you have a geometry, your query class may or may not implement IFeatureClass.

Comment: If I define the QueryClass then do I have to actually implement ITable and/or IFeatureClass? If I don't implement one of those interfaces is the "class" still usable?